# Bing Map in Windows 8 App

Tags: windows-8, bing-maps

i am trying to implement Bing Map in my windows 8 application. I have installed sdk from 
[here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0c341dfb-4584-4738-949c-daf55b82df58)
 and configured my application as defined in
[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408457/Using-Bing-Maps-For-Windows-8-Metro-Apps-Csharp-Ja).

but still I am getting errors like:

> The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007F)

Comment: Can you post some code and the stacktrace to indicate where the Exception is occurring?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. apparently there's 2 different Bing Maps SDK's available.
I had the SDK for Metro Style Apps which wouldn't work.
There's another one called Bing Maps SDK for Windows Store apps, which can be found [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb764f67-6b2c-4e14-b2d3-17477ae1eaca).

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408457/Using-Bing-Maps-For-Windows-8-Metro-Apps-Csharp-Ja) too, which helped me get the Map view working.

Answer (score 0):

Install an extension to visual studio. It should be provided with SDK. That add Bing maps by reference to your project (sometimes you need to restart VS). After that in your toolbox you should have Map element available

Comment: i have got the Map element in my toolbox: but when i try to use the element, it displays " cannot create an instance of "Map".. how to solve this problem

Comment: ok so be so nice and give us some code. Post how did you put it into your xaml. Second thing is that you need to set on wich platform you want to compile the project (x86 or x64).

Comment: x86...  <Maps:Map x:Name="bingMap" Credentials="Key" Margin="0,0,267,0"/>

Comment: `Credentials="Key"` - I must ask. Do you set your true key where you have Key word and you posted here word "Key" so we don`t see it or you rly have word "Key" there ?